# Fetching data to a React.js component is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, webpack, fetch

I have this **quote.jsx** file with a React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import './quotes.css';

export default class Quotes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="quotes">
        {
          fetch('/random_quote')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => json.text())
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you may see, it uses **fetch** to get a JSON object with data related to a quote (quote text and author) and display some this data.

When I use **webpack** to bundle my system, I'm getting this warning message:

> WARNING in ./fe/~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js
>   9:12-34 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

And when I run my web system and visit the URL who should display this component, I got the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Quotes`.

There is no error in my back-end and the JSON is being correctly generated and returned. This is not an issue.

I am relatively new to React.js and had never seen this message before.

Can someone help me with this? I've been fighting this error all my Sunday and have no more options to deal with it.

Comment: Perform the fetch inside `componentDidMount` then save the result into state, and in `render` access the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't perform the `fetch` inside `render`, instead do it in `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`.

Here is how I would implement it:

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import './quotes.css';

export default class Quotes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/random_quote')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({text: json.text()});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="quotes">
        {this.state.text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```